# Put focus on input field after it will be conditionally rendered in Vue

Tags: vue.js

### Target

On click to "edit" button, input field appears and automatically focused.

```html
<button v-if="!editingMode" @click="editingMode = !editingMode">edit</button>
<input v-else type="text" value ref="input">
```

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      editingMode: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onClickButton() {
      this.editingMode = true;
      this.$refs.input.focus();
    }
  }
};
```

[Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-dust-pod0q?file=/src/App.vue)

### Problem

Because re-rendering in Vue synchronous, when we calling `this.$refs.input.focus()`, input field could be not rendered yet. I experienced two cases:

1. Input is not mounted yet. In this case, `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined"` will occur.
2. No this error, but no focus too. It looks like there is the interval between input field mounted and ready to manipulations.

Comment: I had a look at your fiddle, there were a few other issues, see my answer, I added a working fiddle for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling it in [this.$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) :

```
methods: {
  onClickButton() {
    this.editingMode = true;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.input.focus();
    })
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-dew-5mcju

Comment: you use an arrow function there is no need for `self = this`